# DataFrame slicing in Python fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, slice

I want to slice my data in Python. The very basic task to slice my dataframe throws unexpected errors at me.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd

test_file = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/testfile.csv")
test_select = test_file[["Category", "Shop"]]
print(test_select[1,1])
```

The code `print(test_select[1,1])` should display the second row of the second column.

The error message:

> File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   KeyError: (1, 1)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Lenovo/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/Dictionary.py", line 8, in 
>       print(h_select[1,1])
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\mindnotez\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2688, in **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_column(key)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\mindnotez\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
>       return self._get_item_cache(key)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\mindnotez\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2489, in _get_item_cache
>       values = self._data.get(item)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\mindnotez\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4115, in get
>       loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\mindnotez\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>     File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>     File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   KeyError: (1, 1)

When I print `print(test_select.head())`, I get the following output:

```
     Category           Shop
0       Jidlo         Albert
1       Jidlo          BILLA
2       Jidlo         Albert
3       Jidlo         Albert
4  Restaurant  Kockafé Freyd
```

Slicing the dataframe like `print(test_select[1:4])`, prints row 1:3.
With the command `print(test_select[1,1])`, I want the second column, second row. However, I receive the error message above.

**Why do I receive the *KeyError* exception?** What am I missing?

I use:

- Python 3.7
- PyCharm
- Anaconda (is installed)

Comment: You can't select data from a dataframe with that syntax. You want `test_select.iloc[1,1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to slice a dataframe

**By row number**

```
df.iloc[[1, 5]] # to get rows 1 and 5

df.iloc[1:6] # to get rows 1 to 5 inclusive
```

You can also narrow it down to a specific column as follows (to avoid [chain indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy))

```
df.iloc[[1, 5], df.columns.get_loc('Shop')]
```

or multiple columns

```
df.iloc[[1, 5], df.columns.get_indexer(['Shop', 'Category'])]
```

**By label based index**

```
# Numeric
df.loc[[1, 5]] # 1 and 5 are considered labels here
df.loc[[1, 5], 'Shop']
df.loc[[1, 5], ['Shop', 'Category']]

# Textual or otherwise
df.set_index('Shop', inplace=True)
df.loc[['BILLA', 'Albert'], 'Category']
```

Comment: The last two examples are examples of chained indexing. This is poor practice.

Answer (score 3):

> The code `print(test_select[1,1])` should display the second row of the
>   second column.

*No, it shouldn't.* The syntax `df[x]` is usually reserved for retrieving a column (series), Boolean row indexing, or row slicing. These uses of `pd.DataFrame.__getitem__`, for which `df[]` is syntactic sugar, aren't conveniently documented. In general, they should be considered shortcuts, and if you are unsure you *should* prefer `loc` / `iloc` / `at` / `iat`, as appropriate.

To retrieve a scalar value via integer positional indexing, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html):

```
df.iat[1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `loc` this is using index and column rather than the position , here looks like your index is from 0 to n so that `loc` is equal to `iloc` when slice the row

```
df.loc[1,'Shop']
'BILLA'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want second row second column you have to use:
df.iloc[1,1]   iloc extracts data based on index

[1,1]  takes the first row index and first column index. output would be 'BILLA'