# How to skip a point in a .csv file if it is larger than x?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data that has some outliers that need to be ignored, but I am struggling to find out how to do this. I need data that is over the value of 500 to be removed/ignored. Below is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib

#convert the files to make sure that only the data needed is selected
INPUT_FILE = 'data.csv'
OUTPUT_FILE = 'machine_data.csv'
PACKET_ID = 'machine'

with open(INPUT_FILE, 'r') as f:
data = f.readlines()
with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w') as f:
for datum in data:
    if datum.startswith(PACKET_ID):
        f.write(datum)

#read the data file
df = pd.read_csv(OUTPUT_FILE, header=None, usecols=[2,10,11,12,13,14])
#plotting the conc
fig,conc = plt.subplots(1,1)
lns1 = conc.plot(df[2],df[11],color="g", label='Concentration')
```

As you can see, I have selected certain columns that I need, but within [11] I only need the data that is less than 500.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example for your `df`? Ideally you shouldn't be slicing `df` as you are, but you should use the `loc, iloc, at, iat` functions.

Comment: @guin0x this is what a teacher gave me and it runs well with my code and is the only code I have so far for this.

Comment: I understand, but for your future reference, try to avoid it. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53798082/dataframe-slicing-in-python-fails) for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to filter your dataframe by that column
like :

```
df = df[(df[11] <= 500)]
```

Your code will then look like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib

#convert the files to make sure that only the data needed is selected
INPUT_FILE = 'data.csv'
OUTPUT_FILE = 'machine_data.csv'
PACKET_ID = 'machine'

with open(INPUT_FILE, 'r') as f:
data = f.readlines()
with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w') as f:
for datum in data:
    if datum.startswith(PACKET_ID):
        f.write(datum)

#read the data file
df = pd.read_csv(OUTPUT_FILE, header=None, usecols=[2,10,11,12,13,14])

# filter your data HERE:
df = df[(df[11] <= 500)]

#plotting the conc
fig,conc = plt.subplots(1,1)
lns1 = conc.plot(df[2],df[11],color="g", label='Concentration')
```

Comment: if I need to apply this say for values that are less than 0, then other values that are over 500, could I u se the same code and simply manipulate it to what I need? (sorry for not including in main question, I have just thought about it!)

Comment: here is a generic filter line : `df = df[(df[11] >= 0) & (df[11] <= 500)]` for values between 0 and 500 for the column 11, change it in any way suits you. Hope that helps ! (by the way, the values inside are conditions, you can add as many as you want, here I put two as you can see)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The data generated is a lot less noisy now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to ignore outliers greater than 500 for column `df[11]` try something like:

```py
df[11] = df[11].where(df[11] <= 500).dropna()
```

Source: [DataFrame.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. The data is a lot less noisy now.